# Как можно упростить/оптимизировать данный код?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

В частности похожие части кода с присвоением значений переменным

```js
private isThumbsCollision(): boolean {
  let fromEdge: number;
  let toEdge: number;
  let thumbSize: number;

  if (this.settings.isVertical === false) {
    thumbSize = this.to.tooltip.element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    fromEdge = this.from.element.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    toEdge = this.to.element.getBoundingClientRect().right;
  } else {
    thumbSize = this.to.tooltip.element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    fromEdge = this.from.element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    toEdge = this.to.element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  }
  return toEdge - fromEdge <= thumbSize;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот так, например, проще и оптимизированней

```
if (this.settings.isVertical) {
    thumbSize = this.to.tooltip.element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    fromEdge = this.from.element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    toEdge = this.to.element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  } else {
    thumbSize = this.to.tooltip.element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    fromEdge = this.from.element.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    toEdge = this.to.element.getBoundingClientRect().right;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Читаемый вариант:

```js
const size_property = this.settings.isVertical
 ? 'height'
 : 'width';

const edge_property = this.settings.isVertical
 ? 'top'
 : 'right';

let thumbSize = this.to.tooltip.element.getBoundingClientRect()[size_property];
let fromEdge = this.from.element.getBoundingClientRect()[edge_method];
let toEdge = this.to.element.getBoundingClientRect()[edge_property];
```

Вырви глаз (зато в три строки):

```js
let thumbSize = this.to.tooltip.element.getBoundingClientRect()[this.settings.isVertical ? 'height': 'width'];
let fromEdge = this.from.element.getBoundingClientRect()[this.settings.isVertical ? 'top' : 'right'];
let toEdge = this.to.element.getBoundingClientRect()[this.settings.isVertical ? 'top' : 'right'];
```